# PHP query from MySQL without duplicating

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to determine a way to query data from a MySQL database and, if there is already a duplicate of that data, to skip it and move to the next one.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to pull a list of department's from a database and list them once for ex:

```
MySQL table
1  Accounting
2  Manufacturing
3  Manufacturing
4  HR
```

I want it to print:

```
Accounting, Manufacturing, HR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT field_name FROM table_name GROUP BY field_name
```

Or [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the department names, you can use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT department_name FROM departments
```